# Is it possible to abstract away repeated parts of XML code?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am developing an android app, and I am trying to implement `HorizontalScrollView` on almost all the activities in the app. (almost 50+).

I am looking to define a class/variable/function in the java file, then call it on the XML file, so that I don't have to retype/copy and paste the code more than 50 times.

Also, if I define a function in my `MainActivity`, is it possible to use it in other java/XML files?

Comment: just create the xml you want duplicated, then use the  <include/> tag to use that resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should only have ONE `Activity` in your app as an entry point and use `Fragments` for different windows, this is an idea which Google is pushing at the moment.

---

Second of all, YES, you can reuse `MainActivity` **function** in other java files, but not in XML files. Example:

Define an interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void triggerMainActivityFunction();
}
```

Then implement this interface in your `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface {
    ...
    @Override
    public void triggerMainActivityFunction() {
        // Do something
    }
    ...
}
```

Define listener in all of the java classes where you want to trigger this function:

```
public class SomeClass extends Fragment {
    ...
    private MyInterface listener;

    @Override
    void onCreate(...) {
        listener = (MyInterface) getActivity();
    }

    // your function to trigger a reusable 
    // function from Activity when user clicks on something
    public void onClick() {
        listener.triggerMainActivityFunction();
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Third, YES, you can reuse XML layouts by using [include](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) tag.

---

Hope this helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 3):

In xml file you can include other xml layout. I think you can use it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. In general, you can create xml layout parts and reuse them, see examples [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts)

Comment: Yes using `<include/>` tag you can reuse some layout in other xml

Comment: Can you mark it as answer to your question, if it was helpful for you of course